# PHP count the number of occurances of values of a variable

Tags: php, counting

This has to do with counting in PHP, and there are numerous questions and examples of that, but none that I can find of what I need to do: count the occurrences of the value of a variable and output that count as its own variable.

The values I want to count and output as variables are each of the 50 state two letter abbreviations, i.e. AL, AK AR...; they are contained in `$state`.

What's the most efficient way to count the number of occurrences of each state and output each as a variable, i.e. `$AL_total` and `$AK_total` and `$AR_total`, etc.?

```
// I have data in the format
// firstname\n lastname \naddress \ncity \nstate \nzip
// This explode strings into array
foreach($values as $val) {
$valuearray = explode("\n", implode($val));

// This assigns variables that are used to echo each field of data
$firstname = $valuearray[0];
$lastname = $valuearray[1];
$address = $valuearray[2];
$city = $valuearray[3];
$state = $valuearray[4];
$zip = $valuearray[5];

// count $state and output as $AL_total , $AK_total , $AR_total , etc.


// And then...

echo $AL_total;

etc....
```

Comment: array_count_values() ?

Comment: aha, I think that's what I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an aproach based in your initial requirements:

```
#inside the loop

$states[$state] = null;

if (!isset(${$state . '_total'})) {
    ${$state . '_total'} = 1;
} else {
    ${$state . '_total'} += 1;
}
```

And then:

```
#after the loop
foreach ($states as $state => $_null) {
    echo "Total ".$state." = ".${$state . '_total'}."\n";
}
```

And if you want to ouput a specific state that you know it:

```
#after the loop
echo "Total AL = ".((isset($AL_total)) ? $AL_total : 0);
```

You can see it runing [here](https://tio.run/##7VXBbtswDL3rKzgvQB0scOuuu6zbihyHBjsUvSVBwdlyLUCRDYsO1hX59oySrNQZCnTorvXBpvyo90hapNu63e@/XLV1K05P4TvUuJVQIiEoA1RLqJpug@TASnWWDG7kyoDGYMLKYFl20lq2CkUP/LCE5IDfynPe1sqC/NXqppRgqVPm3jI5NYBdhw9CTLaoe2nhKywF8LVMHHO@MlEkP4gEDV7Pf3j@PFnP/n3P9Sv23Lxiz@IttrfY/j@29aUQ3H0SixrS2CRowZlTePSc4bVvJO6focvSZGWSGahNWHn/KZO5DbEh0Vp1byxssVP4UzMz1UjckhJ6K0vg9pRFzTenXimpS2gqPxiC7mEYsOwoiOUZR@0dDhPiGM8jHsfGMXweYT9LjrGPEQsD5hi8iCBX7y/o0/op96LpDUUGNJxUT21PvqzzxR01hBpmbF@P7JuDLanIxCgIuwzPNUuaXutBSFWQvlPWSkonj4NYBieB5mQ3jV/PEz3jwGx5SGcHUlv5kvuHJ3@xGx@aEKTPbijaN5jcuUhjCP4jJ7c@vyQLXlnCAfDiGanMHa1LJ/IeK5Kd/0XopmnFmGi@8ARpOtQgVpYTvxrV@TOc8bHc7/8A)

---

And if you prefer to get a single array using array_count_values() function (as commented by @nice_dev) the do the following:

```
#inside the loop
$states_count[] = $state;
```

And then:

```
#after the loop
$count_by_state = array_count_values($states_count);
print_r($count_by_state);
echo "Total AL = ".(isset($count_by_state['AL']) ? $count_by_state['AL'] : 0);
```

will output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [AN] => 1
    [AK] => 5
    [AR] => 5
    [AL] => 4
)
Total AL = 4
```

You can see it running [here](https://tio.run/##7VRNT8MwDL3nV1gFiU6aGOPjwoemHRETh2m3rqpMm9JIXVol7sRA/PbhpmSsEwcEV3ponTz7@aXRc13U2@3tpC5qMRrBPRS4lpAhISgNVEjIK7NCasFcGUsaV3KpocQuhKXGLDPSWo5SRRv@WEJqgVflOBeFsiBf6rLKJFgySj9bJqcK0BjcCHG8xrKRFu4gEsBPFLTM46X2Tca7Jl0PXk8fHf84iIc/r3n4Rc38FzWzf23/2v6uLb4Rgt0nMS0g9CZBC204gDfH2W07I7F/Pl0WBksdDEGtupXLHzBZW@ANidaqZ21hjUbhU8nMVCCxJSU0VmbA9pRpwa@2e65kmUGVu8HQ9d0NA267JyI6Y9UuYTch@vjY435s9OFzD7tZ0scuPNYNmD546UH@ewfQVfx19rRqNHkG1HyohuqG3G@dzhKqCEsYcvywF893saT0VOyJsIkjjOK2pdu5Ee9CHGFO0rjxWVZVLY5dVvK0Sbx0p6wrTrqbDXuMfF01T0pKTHhQzIi7mGDhNE1nzBachspaSYe50cl0dhIPYALfAnANZ0y33X4A)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and it works. nice_dev pointed out the possible use of array_count_values(). Would that be easier?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: It depends of how do you want to manage them. First I did it in the way you were asking for in your inital post. Now I have added the `array_count_values()` function that will generate an array with all values that you could access via `$count_by_state[state]` instead `$state_total` vars. As you wish. Surely the `array_count_values()` solution looks better and cleaner than the other.

Comment: Thanks! Using array_count_values works better for me; the first example killed my loop for some reason. And it appears to be more efficient.

Comment: Ah, `Warning: Undefined array key "AL"` when AL is 0, I guess. Do we need to check if a key exists when we `echo "Total AL = ".$count_by_state['AL'];` ?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: I have edited my answer and added the array verification. Also updated the link to test it again.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Could you update your question at the end with that scenario?  I mean, put an array where that is happening and then I could investigate further why it not runs, thanks.  Or modify the [current example that I posted](https://tuit.cat/ZidZN) and give me the new link (use a url shortener for that, it do not fit in a comment)

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake; some bad input data. I deleted my comment but I guess you saw it before I deleted it.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I see, perfect, I was reviewing the code and I was wondering what was happening really, hehe.. no problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an associative array where the keys are the states and the values are the counts, e.g.:

```
# before your loop:
$stateCount = [];

# in your loop:
if( ! isset( $stateCount[$state] ) ) { # first time $state is seen, init to 1
    $stateCount[$state] = 1;
} else {
    $stateCount[$state]++;
}
```

Comment: nice_dev pointed out the possible use of array_count_values(). Would that be easier?

Comment: imo, your array for counting would be unnecessarily large (and use up more memory) with using `array_count_values`

Comment: That's interesting. How do I output the total for i.e., AL? Is that `echo $al`?

Comment: I recommend reading up on how associative arrays work in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.  To access AL, you would use `echo $stateCount['AL'];`